# System.InvalidOperationException on InsertOnSumbit()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, invalidoperationexception

I have a database which has a table named `ProductLikes` (which has two columns: `UserId` and `ProductId`). In my asp.net webform application, I use LINQ to SQL, and I've implemented the .dbml file.

When accessing (Select, Update, Delete, Insert) to all of my tables, everything works just fine; except for when I wanna insert data into table `ProductLikes`.

I've written a method which inserts a row into the table. when it arrives at `InsertOnSubmit` method, `System.InvalidOperationException` throws:

```
public bool ToggleLikeProduct(long productId, long userId)
{
    bool result = false;
    ProductLike productLike = db.ProductLikes.Where(i => i.UserId == userId && i.ProductId == productId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (productLike == null)
    {
        //Here:
        db.ProductLikes.InsertOnSubmit(new ProductLike { UserId = userId, ProductId = productId });
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        db.ProductLikes.DeleteOnSubmit(productLike);
        result = false;
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
    return result;
}
```

What's the problem?

Note: everything else such as Connection to SQL Server, implementing of LINQ to SQL classes, passing parameters, calling method and... is implemented correctly.

Comment: did you try and write a try-catch to see the error in detail ? normally there should be a specific error message

Comment: Is there an InnerException value on the Exception thrown? There should be more detail on what's causing the issue, e.g., you tried to manually set the identity column, etc.